# how to merge two excel text cells and skip "0" values?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

My excel spreadsheet:

- cell A1 contains `0`
- cell B1 contains `Short Sentence 1`
- cell C1 contains `Short Sentence 2`

I would like to have one cell with:
`Short Sentence 1, Short Sentence 1`

Comment: You mean `Short Sentence 1, Short Sentence 2` perhaps? And have you tried looking at the formula `=CONCATENATE()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula

```
=IF(A1=0;"";A1&", ") & IF(B1=0;"";B1&", ") & IF(C1=0;"";C1)
```